# Can i use a 36w transformer to power a 41w neon sign?

Tags: wiring

I have a neon sign that has a luminaire rating 12v dc 41w and a transformer input 100 240 v 50/60hz. output 12vdc 3a , can i use a transformer  of 36w with the similar input and output ?

Answer (score 1):

Using just the figures you gave us and not knowing anything more about the transformer, the transformer would be 13.6% overloaded if you hooked it up to the sign. It would work but the question is for how long before the transformer failed due to overload. You're best bet is to get the right size transformer. Just Google it.

Comment: OK , was asking as the power supply is similar to a computer power supplying but is only 36w , hence asking if it will suffice ?

Comment: Those power supplies don't like to be overloaded. It will suffice but for how long, no one knows. Try it and see what happens.